# Removing an inherited class from an element

Tags: jquery, css, html

How can I remove an inherited class. I have a UL with a `JavaScript` class `(js--main-nav)`. In the UL I have a few `li` (the ones with the class="socialIconHeader") that I would like to remove the inherited `js--main-nav` class from. I have tried with `CSS` and `jQuery` however I was not able to get it to work. Any input on how to remove the inherited class would be appreciated.

```html
<nav>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/Logo_white.png" alt="ATCD Logo" class="logo" />
    <img src="assets/images/Logo_black.png" alt="ATCD Logo" class="logo-black" />
    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
      <li> 
        <a href="#features">About</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="https://www.behance.net/" target="_blank">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#states">Locations</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://atcdllc2.atcdllc.com/forum/">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/atcdllc">
          <i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/atcdllc">
          <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
          <i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon">
      <i class="ion-navicon-round"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove 'socialIconHeader' class? Can you reframe your question clearly?

Comment: He wants to stop the `<li>` from inheriting the `js--main-nav` class i think

Comment: DMcCallum83 is correct. I want the li's with the class socialIconHeader to not inherit the js--main-nav.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".socialIconHeader").removeClass("js--main-nav");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('li.socialIconHeader').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('js--main-nav'))
    $(this).removeClass('js--main-nav');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/Logo_white.png" alt="ATCD Logo" class="logo" />
    <img src="assets/images/Logo_black.png" alt="ATCD Logo" class="logo-black" />
    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
      <li> 
        <a href="#features">About</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="https://www.behance.net/" target="_blank">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#states">Locations</a>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://atcdllc2.atcdllc.com/forum/">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/atcdllc">
          <i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/atcdllc">
          <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="socialIconHeader">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
          <i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon">
      <i class="ion-navicon-round"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm just looping through all the `li` which has class `socialIconHeader` and then checking for class `js--main-nav` present or not, if present then only removing the class.

Hope this will help.